# Dojo Enhanced Grid nested sorting not able to sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, dojo, grid

I am using Dojo Enhanced grid with pagination and nested sorting plugin. Here in the grid, when i click the down arrow on the column header, the elements are not getting sorted properly. 
Suppose if i have :
xhar
amar
Memid1
Memid2
1
2

So when i sort them they become:
1
2
Memid1
Memid2
amar
xhar

And i want the order to be : 1 2 amar Memid1 Memid2 xhar 
why is that? what can be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

Like Lucian said, you could write your own sorting method. As you can read in the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid.html), you can enable custom sorting by adding the `NestedSorting` plugin. You can do this by adding the following:

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.NestedSorting");
```

and then you only need to set the attribute `nestedSorting: true` on your grid object.

Sorting itself is not depending on the grid, but on the store. You can read more about custom sorting in the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#custom-sorting) of the `ItemFileReadStore`. What you want to do is something like this:

```
grid.store.comparatorMap = new Object();
grid.store.comparatorMap["col1"] = function(a, b) {
    if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
         return -1;   
    } else if (a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

As you can see I modified the comparator map for `col1`, you need to modify this to the columns you need.
The function itself is pure JavaScript and works like comparison in many languages. If string a should come before string b when sorting, return a negative number (-1), when both strings are equal you need to return 0 and if string b should come before string a it should be 1.
To enable case insensitivity you need to compare the lowercase variants of both strings.

I updated my previous JSFiddle (previous question) with the new additions and tested it under Dojo 1.6. The result can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KDTcC/6/).

Answer (score 0):

make  a column that has only lower case values and sort using this column but do not show this column in your grid. keep this column hidden. lower case letters seem to come after upper case letters so that is why you need to make everything lower case.

another possibility would be to write your own sorting method and connect it to your grid.